# How to convert from bytes to string?

Tags: python, c, opencv, arduino, serial-communication

I am using OpenCV library in Python to detect faces and calculate the centre point of the rectangle(X,Y) formed around the face to control servos connected to an arduino. I converted it to bytes since python uses unicode, like this

```
data = "X{0:f}Y{1:f}".format(xx, yy)
bdata = b'data'
arduino.write(bdata)
```

I have to recieve these bytes in arduino program via serial communication, and it is receiving. The problem is i can't decode it back to string so the program can read I have tried and searched as much as on google read so many forums but nothing I am beginner in this as I have mechanical engg background so a total noob. I dont even know if this possible. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bdata = b'data'
```

This is creating a string of four bytes, representing the characters `d`, `a`, `t`, `a` in ASCII encoding. That's probably not what you meant!

What you should do instead is encode the `data` string into bytes using the `encode` function. This requires that you think about the encoding; probably ASCII is fine for this situation, because you don't have any "special" characters:

```
bdata = data.encode('ascii')
```

As a general tip, it can be useful to experiment in the Python interpreter, for example:

```
>>> xx = 4.3
>>> yy = 7.1
>>> data = "X{0:f}Y{1:f}".format(xx, yy)
>>> bdata = b'data'
>>> bdata
b'data'
>>> bdata = data.encode('ascii')
>>> bdata
b'X4.300000Y7.100000'
```